# c# webbrowser GetAttribute("onclick") doesn't work

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I want to click on button that has the following HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="ExecuteBid('46160');" title="ExecuteBid" class="btn btn-custom3">Bid</a>
```

The problem is that the only attribute I can use is onclick, because there are more buttons on the site that use the same name as href, title and class, if I use any of these the click will be on more than one button, and I just want to click on this specific button.

My code:

```
HtmlElementCollection elementButton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
foreach (HtmlElement elementyButton in elementButton)
{
 if (elementyButton.GetAttribute("onclick") == "ExecuteBid('46097');")
 {
  elementyButton.InvokeMember("click");
 }
}
```

But `elementyButton.GetAttribute("onclick")` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried viewing your chrome console or your web console by clicking F12?

See what errors they are throwing back, that could help you see. Feel free to post the errors here.